# turn elements to NaN after first negative

Tags: matlab

I've got a three dimensional array in Matlab. The first dimension is time, the second is Humidity, and the third is Temperature. If a Temperature value is < 0, I want every subsequent temperature value to be turned to NaN.

For example if the array is:

```
>> sampl = randn(4,3,2)

sampl(:,:,1) =

  0.79487     0.71017     -0.39167
  0.51754     -1.3068     0.84166
  0.49461     0.74159     0.082784
  0.66393     1.4677      0.31467


sampl(:,:,2) =

  0.78981      1.3096        1.0434
 -0.80122      0.16037      -1.0682
 -0.32565      -2.1182      -0.31723
  0.28468      0.70708      1.4797
```

What's the most efficient way to turn this into:

```
sampl(:,:,1) = 

  0.79487     0.71017     NaN
  0.51754     NaN         NaN
  0.49461     NaN         NaN
  0.66393     NaN         NaN


sampl(:,:,2) =

  0.78981     1.3096      1.0434
  NaN         0.16037     NaN
  NaN         NaN         NaN
  NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Specifically, for a particular slice, we want to process along each column, and as soon as we encounter a negative number in one column, we want that location to be `NaN` as well as all row locations for that same column that follow this NaN value to also be `NaN`.

Comment: Can you further explain how you went from your sample input to sample output?  It doesn't seem to correspond with your problem statement.

Comment: Never mind, I think I figured it out.  For a particular slice, we want to process along each column, and as soon as you encounter a negative number in one column, do you want that location to be `NaN` as well as all row locations for that same column that follow this `NaN` value?

Comment: That's exactly right. Better explanation than I gave.

Comment: Ah ok :) lol.  Yeah I'm trying to figure out what it was you were trying to get at.  Seems I have a knack for doing that.  Divakar calls me a "mentalist" because of it.  With that, I'm writing an answer.  Give me a few moments.

Comment: You're welcome! I wrote an answer, and also included this explanation in your post.  Hope that's ok!  Let me know if my answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another easy way is to find those locations that are negative in the original matrix, creating another matrix that sets those values to`NaN`, invoke a [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) or a cumulative sum along all the rows for each column in each slice of this new matrix, then set the corresponding locations in this `cumsum` result to `NaN` in the original matrix to obtain the final result:

```
>> out = sampl;
>> out(out < 0) = NaN;
>> out = cumsum(out);
>> sampl(isnan(out)) = NaN

sampl(:,:,1) =

    0.7949    0.7102       NaN
    0.5175       NaN       NaN
    0.4946       NaN       NaN
    0.6639       NaN       NaN


sampl(:,:,2) =

    0.7898    1.3096    1.0434
       NaN    0.1604       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

The reason why `cumsum` is useful here is because we would essentially examine each column independently along its rows and keep accumulating over all of the rows for each column which has valid entries **until** we hit a `NaN` value for a column.  After this value, subsequent values in the `cumsum` would become `NaN` for each column in each slice independently.  As such, after we hit the first `NaN` in a column, no matter what values we encounter after (`NaN` or a valid number), the result in the `cumsum` would still be `NaN`.  This effectively propagates `NaN` values after we encounter the first negative in a column for your matrix.  The last bit is to find those locations in this matrix and set the corresponding locations in the original matrix to `NaN`, thus giving our result.

Comment: haha wow so simple good job! I definitely over-complicated this. +1

Comment: @Benoit_11 - No problem my friend :)  I was working on this while you got an answer.  I +1ed you too btw!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `accumarray`.

First, get the number of rows and reshape `sampl` to get a 2D array; it's easier to work with:

```
NumRow = size(sampl,1);

a = reshape(sampl,NumRow,[])
```

`a` looks like this:

```
a =

    0.7949    0.7102   -0.3917    0.7898    1.3096    1.0434
    0.5175   -1.3068    0.8417   -0.8012    0.1604   -1.0682
    0.4946    0.7416    0.0828   -0.3256   -2.1182   -0.3172
    0.6639    1.4677    0.3147    0.2847    0.7071    1.4797
```

Then find the first row index, for each column, that is negative:

```
[row,col] = find(a<0);
b = accumarray(col,row,[],@min);
```

Now `b` looks like this:

```
b =

     0
     2
     1
     2
     3
     2
```

Before inserting NaN's, change the 0  so that whole columns are not filled with NaN's using the colon operator (see next step):

```
b(b==0) = NumRow+1;
```

Finally loop through your array and insert NaN's starting from the corresponding index in `b` until the last row for every column. Also reshape `a` to get the same size as your initial array:

```
for k = 1:size(a,2)
a(b(k):NumRow,k) = NaN;
end

out = reshape(a,size(sampl))
```

Out:

```
out(:,:,1) =

    0.7949    0.7102       NaN
    0.5175       NaN       NaN
    0.4946       NaN       NaN
    0.6639       NaN       NaN


out(:,:,2) =

    0.7898    1.3096    1.0434
       NaN    0.1604       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Here is the whole code that you can copy/paste to run:

```
clear
clc

NumRow = size(sampl,1);

a = reshape(sampl,NumRow,[])

[row,col] = find(a<0);
b = accumarray(col,row,[],@min)

b(b==0) = NumRow+1;

for k = 1:size(a,2)
a(b(k):NumRow,k) = NaN;
end

out = reshape(a,size(sampl))
```

Answer (score 4):

Missing a [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)-based solution, anyone?

```
[val, ind] = max(sampl<0); %// ind gives row index of first negative value, if any
ind(~val) = inf; %// if no negative values, set ind to inf so it has no effect
sampl(bsxfun(@ge, (1:size(sampl,1)).', ind)) = NaN; %'// logical indexing to fill NaNs
```

Comment: Leave it to you for `bsxfun`!  +1